# Jenkins build with Access DataBase Engine on C# for Selenium Tests,Getting Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, oledbconnection

For my selenium Nnuint tests, Access Data Base Engine used to read data from Excel sheet.While these tests are running from Jenkins, i am getting below error message.

```
Invalid : Automation_Smoke_Tests.CategoryExecution.CategorybaseExcetion
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at NUnit.Framework.TestCaseSourceAttribute.GetTestCaseSource(IMethodInfo method) in C:\src\nunit\nunit\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Attributes\TestCaseSourceAttribute.cs:line 277
   at NUnit.Framework.TestCaseSourceAttribute.GetTestCasesFor(IMethodInfo method) in C:\src\nunit\nunit\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Attributes\TestCaseSourceAttribute.cs:line 173
--InvalidOperationException
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelUtilities.GetWorksheetNames(ExcelQueryArgs args)
   at LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory.GetWorksheetNames()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually running into a similar issue right now. It looks like the machine hosting the Jenkins server doesn't have the correct access engine installed.

I found that I had to have the 2010 version installed. This is where it gets interesting for me. The access engine has 2 variations - a regular version and then an x64 version. I had to have the NON x64 version installed so my tests would run locally in Visual Studio but to get them to execute in Jenkins then I needed the x64 version.

You should be able to find the 2010 downloads here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255.

Comment: Adding a follow-up.

I found that if you change the Default Processor Architecture from x86 to x64 then you can use the x64 version of the access engine for both Visual Studio and Jenkins.